# Doctrine and MySQL Many to Many clear removes child

Tags: php, mysql, sql, doctrine-orm

I have some serious problem with Many To Many relation. In my scenario, a `Candidate` can be connected with many `Projects` and `Project` may have many `Candidates`.

```
CREATE TABLE `CANDIDATE` (    
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,     
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) )ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE `PROJECT` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `PROJECT_CANDIDATE` (
  `CANDIDATE_ID` INT NULL ,
  `PROJECT_ID` INT NULL ,

  CONSTRAINT `FK_PROJECT_CANDIDATE`
    FOREIGN KEY (`CANDIDATE_ID` )
    REFERENCES `CANDIDATE` (`ID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

  CONSTRAINT `FK_CANDIDATE_PROJECT`
    FOREIGN KEY (`PROJECT_ID` )
    REFERENCES `PROJECT` (`ID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Doctrine mapping looks like this:

```
class Project
{
    //.... other fields

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Candidate", mappedBy="projects", fetch="LAZY",cascade={"persist","merge"},orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $candidates;
}



class Candidate
{
        //.... other fields
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Project", inversedBy="candidates", fetch="LAZY",cascade={"persist","merge"},orphanRemoval=true)
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="project_candidate",
     *   joinColumns={
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="CANDIDATE_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="PROJECT_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $projects;
}
```

My question is, why when removing candidates from project like this:

```
 //get $project with EntityManager
 $project->candidates->clear();
```

Also entries in `Candidates` table are removed, even thought I have `ON UPDATE/DELETE NO ACTION' for FK in`PROJECT_CANDIDATE`?

Comment: Is the INNODB engine disabled by any chance? Check `my.cnf` for `--skip-innodb`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's because of the `orphanRemoval=true` option at the ManyToMany annotation declaration.

Please refer to the proper [section](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#orphan-removal) of Doctrine 2 documentation.